# Why does Deno flag a syntax error that does not happen using nodejs?

Tags: syntax, deno

I converted a VB.Net program to JS to run on Deno. I wrote a little class to create the needed functionality of a .Net ArrayList component. Shown below:

```
  export class ArrayList extends Array {
    constructor() {
      super()
      this.add = (obj) => {
        super.push(obj)
      }
      this.item = (key) => {
        let obj = super.valueOf()[key]
        return obj
      }
      this.getUpperBound = () => {
        return super.valueOf().length - 1
      }
      this.clear = () => {
        super.valueOf().length = 0
      }
    }
  }
```

When I test it in a nodejs environment, it has no syntax error. But testing in a Deno environment, I get the error shown below.

```
Error formatting: src/plannerFiles/ClassArrayList.js
   Line 10, column 15: Expected ';', '}' or <eof>

  this.add(obj) {
                ~
```

Line 10 is: "this.add = (obj) => {"

I don't know how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What command are you using to run it? I'm not getting any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your class like that

```
export class ArrayList extends Array {
    constructor() {
      super()
    }

    add = (obj) => {
      this.push(obj)
    }

    item = (key) => {
      let obj = this.valueOf()[key]
      return obj
    }

    getUpperBound = () => {
      return this.valueOf().length - 1
    }

    clear = () => {
      this.valueOf().length = 0
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for that quick answer. As a newbie to Node/Deno, coming from React, I was searching for info about building classes. Where is this level of info found?

Comment: This is not about deno,this is about typescript. React class extends from Component, so you can set any parameter in constructor.